# Is there a way to speed up LOAD CSV of 120M relationships into 10M nodes avoiding cartesian product in Neo4j?

Tags: csv, neo4j

I am trying to create 120M relationships between 10M nodes(:Homes). I have already created all the (:Homes) nodes and created an index on (:Homes).id.

```
CREATE INDEX ON :Homes(id)
```

This is my code for inserting into the database from a local CSV file. Each row in the CSV file has `home1_id` and `home2_id` and I am trying to create a relationship `home1 --> home2`

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 50000
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///relationships.csv" AS row
MATCH (home1:Homes {id: toInteger(row.home1_id)}),(home2:Homes {id: toInteger(row.home2_id)})
CREATE (home1)-[:Recommends]->(home2)
```

Running this currently seems like it is going to take 1-2 hours. Are there any optimizations I can make?

Comment: If `Homes` nodes have unique `id` values, then you wouldn't really have a "Cartesian product" problem since every `MATCH` would only produce a single pair of nodes.

Comment: I still get the warning of "Cartesian product" and it takes really long to execute (a little over 2 hours)

Comment: The warning does not always indicate there is a practical problem. It is also good that you have a relevant index. Note also that you are getting around 20K relationships created per second.

Comment: That sounds about right as 120M is taking 2 hours. So it seems like not much can be done to further optimize and speed this up?